# Select empty keys in dictionary?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, time-complexity

I am adding values in a dictionary, and I am popping them at will. Dictionary keys are integers that are incremented as being added, like a row number in a table.

```
example = {1: data1,
           2: data2,
           3: data3,
           4: data4,
           5: data5}
```

Imagine I removed `2`. Now when I want to add a new element to the dictionary, I want `2` to be added instead of `6`. Here is other details of the issue.

- This can be done by linear search, which I don't want.
- This can be done by keeping a `removed` set. Which is more feasible than linear search in time complexity terms if not in memory.

My question is, this can be easily implemented, but is there a built-in type for the matter?

Comment: Instead of completely removing a key, can you just set it's value to null or empty string and then have a simple loop that inserts a new value the first time it encounters your condition?

Comment: @SergChernata That is still linear search my friend.

Comment: You realize making any such operation thread-safe/reentrant would be a royal pain, right?

Comment: @ShadowRanger You seem correct, but let's don't let this halt our effort to see if there is a way. Well there is a way actually, I was actually curious about a built-in type. Which I failed to find in the documentation(and google).

Comment: @Rockybilly ah, sorry man. Is there any semantic significance to the keys? Maybe there's an approach where you pick a key to delete or re-create based on some logic.

Comment: @Rockybilly or maybe you can take the key that has just been emptied and push it to end or beginning of the stack? That way you can know exactly where to write new data.

Comment: This smells a bit of [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Can you explain what you're trying to do at a somewhat higher level? There is no built-in that does exactly what you want, but a higher level description might determine there is a better way to accomplish this in general.

Comment: @SergChernata That is the same of the second solution I suggested when asking the question. Which seems like the best option, if there is not a build-in one.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Actually **There is no built-in that does exactly what you want** pretty much answers my question.

Comment: why would you want to do that? are you expecting a performance gain? (there is none [...or close to none]).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Yes, more like a theoritical question. So cannot be considered premature optimization.

Comment: and where do you see a 'linear search'? have you looked at the implementation details of `dict`? here are the [time complexities for `dict` operations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist The linear part is to find the smallest removed key, not dict operations themselves of course.

Comment: sorry, that was far from clear for me.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Probably my fault for not explaining clearly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to store the removed keys, there may be many of them, and at a random time you want to pop the smallest of them.

That seems perfect for the [`heapq` priority heap structure](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html). Adding an arbitrary item and popping the smallest is easy. Each of those is done in O(log(n)) time, where n is the number of stored, previously deleted items.

If you know more about the frequency of deleting and re-adding keys or the maximum/usual number of deleted items, you may be able to find something better. But `heapq` is great for general use.

Your "removed set" idea would be linear time for finding the smallest item, so heapq is better if that operation is done often.

Comment: Yes, my removed set idea was rather incorrect if more than single element is to be removed first. Does using heapq better than constructing a list with `bisect`. ?

Comment: `bisect` is used to *find* an item in O(log(n)) time. However, the structure must be ordered, which means *adding* or *deleting* an item is O(n). The `heapq` priority heap is O(1) for finding the minimum, and O(log(n)) in *both* adding any new item and popping the minimum, as well as for some other operations. It is an ideal structure when you only need the smallest item when you access the structure, as in your case.

Comment: Then this seems like the best solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a fleshed-out example of using the `heapq` module as @Rory Daulton already suggested. It maintains a priority queue of indices of removed items in a list named `free`. It then reuses them whenever possible as new items are added.

To support adding items even when there are no free indices available, it also keeps track of the highest unused index in a separate variable called `next-index`. This value is use when there aren't aren't any indices to reused and never-before-used new ones are required.

```
import heapq

example = {1: 'data1',
           2: 'data2',
           3: 'data3',
           4: 'data4',
           5: 'data5'}

free = []
next_index = max(example.keys()) + 1

def remove_item(d, index):
    del d[index]
    heapq.heappush(free, index)

def add_item(d, data):
    global next_index

    try:
        index = heapq.heappop(free)
    except IndexError:
        index = next_index
        next_index += 1
    d[index] = data

remove_item(example, 2)
remove_item(example, 5)

add_item(example, 'data6')
add_item(example, 'data7')
add_item(example, 'data8')

print(example)
```

Output:

```
{1: 'data1', 2: 'data6', 3: 'data3', 4: 'data4', 5: 'data7', 6: 'data8'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @rorydaulton response with a dict subclass:

```
import heapq

class Table(dict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.removed = []
        self.last = 0
        super(Table, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _get_next_key(self):
        if len(self.removed)==0:
            self.last += 1
            key = self.last
        else:
            key = heapq.heappop(self.removed)
        return key

    def additem(self, value):
        key = self._get_next_key()
        self[key] = value
        return key

    def delitem(self, key):
        super(Table, self).__delitem__(key)
        heapq.heappush(self.removed, key)
```

Then you could do

```
>>> t = Table()
>>> t.additem(43) 
>>> t.additem(55)
>>> t.additem(46)
>>> t
{1: 43, 2: 55, 3: 46}
>>> t.delitem(2)
>>> t.additem(1234567)
>>> t
{1: 43, 2: 1234567, 3: 43}
```